# CentOS 7 sshd seems not to work?

Tags: centos, docker, sshd

I started `sudo systemctl start sshd` but I am not able to connect from outside to the CentOS 7 machine. However, on the CentOS 7 machine I can access other servers via `ssh`.

What did I miss?

#### UDATE #1

I've confirmed the following based on slm's answer:

- `sshd` service is up and binding to port 22 on IP 131.181.10.150
- I can perform a `curl -v telenet://131.181.10.150:22` and see a 'Connected' msg.

My issue is when I attempt to `ssh` to the server:

```
$ ssh lor@131.181.10.150
ssh: connect to host 131.181.10.150 port 22: Operation timed out
```

#### UDATE #2

I remembered when I used `docker-compose` that it started to download the containers suddenly I lost the ability to start `ssh` connection.

Looking at the number of interfaces using `ip link show` turned up `docker0` NIC + many others.

I then attempted to disable the Docker service & firewalld and I'm still unable to connect.

```
$ sudo systemctl stop docker
$ sudo systemctl stop firewalld
```

Still no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `sshd` service it's pretty straight forward to set up and get going.

#### 1. Start service

Make sure that the service is up and running/listening on port 22.

*start service*

```
$ sudo systemctl start sshd
```

*check status*

```
$ sudo systemctl status sshd
● sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-07-24 22:24:00 EDT; 1h 40min left
     Docs: man:sshd(8)
           man:sshd_config(5)
 Main PID: 1270 (sshd)
    Tasks: 1
   CGroup: /system.slice/sshd.service
           └─1270 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

Jul 24 22:24:00 centos7 systemd[1]: Starting OpenSSH server daemon...
Jul 24 22:24:00 centos7 systemd[1270]: Executing: /usr/sbin/sshd -D
Jul 24 22:24:00 centos7 sshd[1270]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Jul 24 22:24:00 centos7 sshd[1270]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Jul 24 22:24:00 centos7 systemd[1]: Started OpenSSH server daemon.
Jul 24 20:31:37 centos7 sshd[1582]: Accepted publickey for vagrant from 10.0.2.2 port 64437 ssh2: RSA SHA256:1vJymfZsu2KZ49lDftGMzz2VEb2Z2Y8PNi9cs55eHGE
Jul 24 20:43:29 centos7 systemd[1]: Trying to enqueue job sshd.service/start/replace
Jul 24 20:43:29 centos7 systemd[1]: Installed new job sshd.service/start as 560
Jul 24 20:43:29 centos7 systemd[1]: Enqueued job sshd.service/start as 560
Jul 24 20:43:29 centos7 systemd[1]: Job sshd.service/start finished, result=done
```

#### 2. Verify service is listening

*check if listening on port 22*

```
$ sudo netstat -tlpn | grep sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1270/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1270/sshd
```

You'll also want to verify that `sshd` is listening on either all interfaces (0.0.0.0) or at least your system's IP address:

```
$ ip a l eth0 | awk '/inet / {print $2}'
192.168.56.101/24
```

So you'd see in the `netstat` output, 192.168.56.101:22, for eg.

#### 3. Firewall

Next check that the firewall is allowing network traffic to reach port 22.

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd  --list-all
FirewallD is not running
```

If it's like this, then traffic can reach port 22. If it looks like this:

```
$ firewall-cmd  --list-all
public (active)
  target: DROP
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0 eth1
  sources:
  services: ssh dhcpv6-client
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

It's allowing traffic for the `ssh` & `dhcpv6-client` services and dropping for everything else. Again this is OK and should allow SSH traffic in.

#### 4. Check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Verify that your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is not blocking external connections. The following options should be set similar to what I'm showing below.

```
$ grep -vE '^#|^$|AcceptEnv|HostKey|Syslog|MAC|Banner|LogLevel|Authorized' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
PermitRootLogin yes
MaxAuthTries 4
HostbasedAuthentication no
IgnoreRhosts yes
PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding no
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
Protocol 2
```

#### 5. Verify

You can confirm using a command like this from one of your external clients:

```
$ timeout 2 curl -v telnet://192.168.56.101:22
* Rebuilt URL to: telnet://192.168.56.101:22/
*   Trying 192.168.56.101...
* Connected to 192.168.56.101 (192.168.56.101) port 22 (#0)
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4 
$
```

**NOTE:** If you see a 'Connected to X.X.X.X' IP address message here, there is nothing inhibiting your network traffic from the client machine where you're running `curl` to the `sshd` server.

#### 6. Docker

In some situations, such as where Docker has been installed, you'll run into a scenario where the `docker0` bridge has added multiple virtual networks within the `docker0` bridge. You can see them like so:

```
$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
bd7594c1dce3        bridge              bridge              local
db24b1e2be58        host                host                local
edf606d533a5        none                null                local
```

In these situations you'll need to remove any extra networks to restore your physical network, so that it's able to route SSH packets correctly. Simply use the command `docker network rm <net id>` to remove anything beyond the standard `bridge`, `host`, and `none`.

#### References

- [docker-compose network creation kicks me out of ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41736187/docker-compose-network-creation-kicks-me-out-of-ssh)